# How do I remove my name from GNOME Shell panel?

Tags: gnome, configuration

When I installed the latest version of Ubuntu with GNOME Shell, I saw it displays my name on the right-hand side of the top panel. I know my own name, I don't need to see it on screen all the time and besides, it takes up way to much space.

How do I remove my name from the GNOME Shell panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) site. There's an extension called [Remove User Name](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/106/remove-user-name/) that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Tweak has that option under Session Control, it's called Fast User Switcher.

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking for, he wants his username not displaying at the top in GNOME shell, not a user switcher for unity.